# Ping pong server using Asynchronous sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, asyncsocket

I usually do socket programming in C/C++ with much ease , but here I have server in C# using 
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx)

I am trying to convert this code into a ping pong server , that is my client written in C sends it ping and server returns pong ,this process continue until client send server "end"

I am unable to do this in this C# server . any helpI want server to keep receiving and sending back the response in a loop

Comment: What actually happens? Have you tried running the C# program in a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Comment: simply it runs the calls